# Changing snap tolerance on ArcMap layout view in batch?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

I have many (60+) .mxd files and I want to change an option on all of them. The option is about setting the snap tolerance (Arcmap > Options > Snap Tolerance). See pic. These are all template mxd's which is why I want to change this setting on multiple, already existing mxd's.

Running ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

A python option or something similar would be a good option.

[image: arcmap options]

Answer (score 1):

The [MapDocument class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm) of ArcPy does not have a property that you can set for this.

Consequently, I think your only option will be to investigate ArcObjects, or to post an ArcGIS Idea which I think will be unlikely to be implemented.